# select и функциии

Tags: php, sql, select, функции

Я подумал что если часто встречаются однотипные запросы, то можно написать функцию которая принимала бы строку запроса $q и возвращала бы $rawdata, для поcледующего fetch`a, но как оказалось сервер сыпется

```
[Thu Apr 21 21:13:48.148495 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1294] AH00051: child pid 7148 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
```

пример кода

```
$q='select stuff from tbl';
$rawdata=sselect($q);
...
...
```

файл inc/fun.inc

```
function sselect($q) {
$ddb = conndb();//connect to db
$rawdata = mysqli_prepare($ddb, $q);
//qres('prep', $rawdata);
$res = mysqli_stmt_execute($rawdata);
//qres('exec', $res);

return ($rawdata);
```

---

Почему так не работает?

Comment: Покаменьтьте вызов функции и посмотрите на ошибки еще раз. Это очень странно

Comment: return ($rawdata);
}

Comment: Вы можете отредактировать свой вопрос и добавить в него `}`

Comment: u__mulder - вы случайно не бот? Что странного? Проверьте код у себя.

Comment: Я тот еще бот ага

Comment: вот пробовал так но ввесь апач почти падает. Ошибку я выше указал

Я еще не понял как редактировать свой вопрорс.

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/company/bitrix/blog/153001/ копайте дальше.

Comment: ага, буду читать. ;)

Comment: вопрос не "ГДЕ ошибка возникает?". Она получается из-за "неправильной" функции.

Почему такое происходит? Потому что при выходе из функции и происходит SEGFAULT - Значит такие функции нельзя создавать(?)

Comment: Вы коннект делаете в функции, после чего возвращаете дескриптор выполненного запроса. НО когда функция завершается, ваша переменная $ddb выходит из области видимости и сборщик мусора ее уничтожает, т.е. закрывает коннект к базе, после чего любые дескрипторы запросов связанные с этим соединением становятся недействительными и их использовать нельзя. Попробуйте коннект все таки сделать один глобальный, на все приложение

Comment: Можно сказать что ы мне помогли разгадать эту тайну. ;) Вопрос закрыт(?)
---
http://itmages.ru/image/view/4176597/cb423cec

ПОСЛЕ возврата 
http://itmages.ru/image/view/4176596/f4746f28

Да. закрытвает подклдючение. Значит так нельзя писать функц.

Я ХОТЕЛ сделать такую функцию, но получается что низзя

Comment: Установка соединения с базой отнимает время, зачем устанавливать соединение при каждом обращении. сделайте его глобальным а остальная часть функции вполне рабочая

Answer (score 1):

Идея неплохая, но сформулирована и реализована  из рук вон плохо.

Во-первых, при чем здесь "однотипные запросы"? Речь, наверное, не о запросах, а об однотипном коде, который требуется для их выполнения?

Во-вторых, реализация просто ужасна. Нет ни малейшего смысла использовать prepare/execute без bind. То есть, в текущем виде эту функцию надо просто выкинуть и вместо нее использовать ванильную query():

```
$ddb = conndb(); // 1 раз в начале
...
$q='select stuff from tbl';
$rawdata=$ddb->query($q);
```

`-` и все будет отлично работать, без всяких самопальных функций. Вот только ни реального сокращения кода, ни безопасности это не даст.

а если уж делать нормально, то

- во-первых, не соединяться с БД при каждом вызове
- во-вторых, возвращать mysqli result а не statement
- **и в самых главных - использовать подготовленные запросы**, а не их имитацию.

Поскольку достичь таких результатов с mysqli новичку довольно струдно, то [надо делать на базе PDO](http://phpfaq.ru/pdo/pdo_wrapper).

И тогда код действительно станет удобным для выполнения любых, а не только однотипных запросов, и при этом безопасным:

```
$q = 'select stuff from tbl where stuff = ?';
$data = DB::run($q, $_GET['stuff'])->fetchAll();
```